# Silverlight SizeChanged event

Tags: silverlight

I don't know what's happening when resizing the main window, but on my laptop the SizeChanged event fires only when i release the mouse, on other computer the event fires immediately when the mouse moves, not when released. I use IE 8. And the other computer also uses IE 8.

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has an option to disable re-drawing of windows until you've finished moving them. Perhaps it is enabled on one machine but not the other? When you drag any window around does it render as a dotted outline, or is the whole window re-drawn as you move it?

On Windows 2003, the option is under *Display Properties*, *Appearance*, *Effects*, *Show window contents while dragging*:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately I don't think is possible to disable that from Silverlight.

Comment: @Alex: it would be unfortunate from a *user's perspective* if Silverlight/IE worked differently and didn't honor the Windows setting.